# How do you duplicate items in creative without a mouse?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can someone tell me how do you duplicate items in creative without a mouse?

Comment: The question body is intended for extra details that wouldn't fit in the title. Don't just copy paste the header into the body.

Answer (score 2):

If you go into the control's settings in Minecraft and change the Pick Block to something on your keyboard or controller, you can use that for duplicating items in creative. However, I don't believe there is any other default method for doing this without the use of a mouse.